# Why does the Bitmap(Image) constructor change PixelFormat?

Tags: c#, duplicates, clone, system.drawing, pixelformat

This code:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bpp24 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(3, 3, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Console.WriteLine("bpp24 pixel format is " + bpp24.PixelFormat.ToString());

System.Drawing.Image bpp24image = bpp24;
Console.WriteLine("bpp24image pixel format is " + bpp24image.PixelFormat.ToString());
System.Drawing.Bitmap duplicate = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(bpp24image);
Console.WriteLine("duplicate pixel format is " + duplicate.PixelFormat.ToString());

System.Drawing.Bitmap clone = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)bpp24.Clone();
Console.WriteLine("clone pixel format is " + clone.PixelFormat.ToString());
```

Produces this output:

> bpp24 pixel format is Format24bppRgb
>
> bpp24image pixel format is Format24bppRgb
>
> duplicate pixel format is Format32bppArgb
>
> clone pixel format is Format24bppRgb

Why did duplicate's PixelFormat change?  A workaround to truly duplicate a Bitmap seems to be the object-level Clone method as shown last (and the Bitmap-level Clone method, but that takes some extra typing), but why can't the higher-level Bitmap(Image) constructor be used to duplicate the Bitmap?

Also see [Bitmap deep copy changing PixelFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044431/bitmap-deep-copy-changing-pixelformat) and [Converting Bitmap PixelFormats in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016406/converting-bitmap-pixelformats-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Doesn't the second link you've posted more-or-less answer your question? It's probably a bug, deep down in Windows GDI+ processing. Incidentally, I've experienced incorrect pixel depth when loading files from disk with Bitmap, so I've gone over to using ImageConverter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array/16576471#16576471

Comment: Does Microsoft actually acknowledge this as a bug?  It could be intended behavior as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228818/651139

Comment: OK, maybe I'm in error. I was unaware of the PreservePixelFormat option.

Comment: Well, that's for BitmapImage (different namespace) -- I'm just thinking the intention could be similar here